# Am I doing the grouping by right?

Tags: sql

I have a system that logs errors. Selection from my errortable:

```
SELECT message, personid, count(*)
FROM errorlog
WHERE time BETWEEN TO_DATE(foo) AND TO_DATE(foo) AND substr(message,0,3) = 'ERR'
GROUP BY personid, message
ORDER BY 3
```

What I want is to see if any user is "producing" more errors then others. For instance ERROR FOO, if user A has 4 errors and user B has 4000, then logic strikes me that user B is doing something wrong.

But can I group the way I do? This is a modified version where the selection only grouped message and counted it, resolving so that ERROR FOO resulted in 4004 from my example over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your query, if the messages are different, then you will get multiple records per person.

If you only want one record per person, you would need to put an [aggregate function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aggregate_function) around `message`

For example you could do:

```
SELECT MIN(message), personid, count(*)
FROM errorlog
WHERE time BETWEEN TO_DATE(foo) AND TO_DATE(foo) AND substr(message,0,3) = 'ERR'
GROUP BY personid, message
ORDER BY 3
```

Here I've changed `message` to `MIN(message)` which will return the first `message` for this person, alphabetically.

---

However if you are happy to return multiple records per person, then I see no problem with your script. It will show a list of `personid` and `message` ordered by the ones which are in the table the most, displaying only records which have a `message` starting with `ERR`

Comment: It's okey that i get multiple records per person. In this selection i want errors, i also log warnings so if a person has multiple and different warnings it's okey and good if they result in multiple records. Thank you for your verification, my SQL is a work in progress :D

Comment: @Jason94 In which case I think your query is fine. I've updated my answer.